# Parse Binary to Decimal

Tags: c, linux, parsing, binary, ascii

I am currently writing a program that stores an array of 'uint16_t' numerical values and then writes them to a binary file. I write to binary due to size considerations (as I will be dealing with large quantities of data). Here is my code so far:

```
static int sizebuf=5;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
     uint16_t buff[sizebuf];
     for(int i=0; i<sizebuf; i++){
            buff[i]=i;
     }
     FILE *fpbin=fopen("test.bin","a+");
     fwrite(buff, sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(buff)/sizeof(uint16_t), fpbin);
     rewind(fpbin);

     uint16_t buffer[sizebuf];
     fread(buff, sizeof(uint16_t), sizebuf, fpbin);
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         printf("%" PRIu16 "\n",buffer[i]);
     }
     fclose(fpbin);
     return 0;
 }
```

When I examine the output in 'test.bin' using 'hexdump' I get the following:

```
 0000000 0000 0001 0002 0003 0004
 000000a
```

First off, I'm not quite sure I understand the presence of the first '000000' and the last '00000a' values. Secondly, how can I go about converting these values back to decimals (namely back to the original numerical values)? The consensus among the sources I have consulted seem to imply there is no standard way of doing this (which I understand given that I am dealing with generic binary outputs), but what is a way I could deal with my specific data for conversion?

Thanks for the help!

---

Edit:
After adding the 'fread' bit of code, I received an output of:

```
5
0
10416
49150
0
```

Comment: Just read the values back into `uint16_t` with `fread`. What do you mean convert back to ascii? `printf` should be able to do all that.

Comment: "back to Ascii text" -- those weren't "ASCII text" to begin with. You probably meant "back to decimal notation".

Comment: Are you sure that last `000000a` isn't on the next line?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. I have updated my code above to reflect Bart's suggestion. I also experimented with the '%d' format identifier. And, yes, I meant back to decimal notation. And yes, the 00000a is on the next line.

Comment: Your `fread` code declares `buffer`, but then reads into `buff`, so when you print out the contents of `buffer`, you're printing uninitialized garbage...

Answer (score 3):

When you examine the output using `hexdump -x` or `od -x`, you see

```
0000000 0000 0001 0002 0003 0004
000000a
```

The leftmost column is the offset in hexadecimal. Both the utilities output a final address without any data, to show the number of bytes parsed.

In other words, the output contains `0x0a`=10 bytes, that can be interpreted as five 16-bit words: `0x0000`=0, `0x0001`=1, `0x0002`=2, `0x0003`=3, and `0x0004`=4.

If you only want the hexadecimal words only, one word per line, use `od -v -An -w2 -t x2`. For decimal words, use `od -v -An -w2 -t d2`.

Please see [`man 1 od`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or [`man 1 hexdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) for further details on the output.

Answer (score 1):

The first `000000` is the offset into the file.  Since that data is from the beginning of the file, the offset is `0`.  The `000000a` is the total file size - 10 bytes in your case (5 array entries times 2 bytes per entry).  Normally that line would be on a new line from the data; are you sure you copied/pasted correctly?

Here are some examples from my machine with your program's output:

```
$ hexdump test.bin # traditional hexdump output
0000000 00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00                
000000a

$ hexdump -d test.bin  # two-byte decimal output
0000000   00000   00001   00002   00003   00004                        
000000a

$ hexdump -x test.bin  # two-byte hexadecimal output 
0000000    0000    0001    0002    0003    0004                        
000000a
```

If you want to generate some decimal output from your binary file, you need to provide some formatting information to hexdump:

```
$ hexdump -e '5/2 "%d " "\n"' test.bin 
0 1 2 3 4
```

Alternately, just make your program output text, rather than binary data, using `fprintf` in your program.  Replace the `fwrite` call with:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sizebuf; i++)
     fprintf(fpbin, "%d\n", buff[i]);
```

Output after making that change:

```
$ cat test.bin 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out I'm going to be dealing with large quantities of data so I wish to write to a binary file first so I don't get use file sizes. I'm just looking for a way to get the original decimal data back from the binary files I create.

Comment: I think my answer addresses that, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score -1):

0000000 actually refers to the line number.  It is not in the binary file, but is generated by your hex dump application.  Your second line will contain 00000010, which represents Each line number will have 16 bytes max.

Each line ends with a line feed, which is ascii 0xa.  Every line will end with that.

Convert each byte to a number, and then use itoa to get the ascii value.

Comment: There is no newline generated by the OP's program.

Comment: The `000000a` is the second "line number". Those aren't really line numbers, though, they're hexadecimal offsets. The first byte is at offset 0000000, and after the last line of output, the hexdump program displays a line with no content, showing what the next byte's offset would be.